# Form of Function of Two Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $V(Q,T)$ be a function of two variables. The exact functional dependence is not known, but it is known that:
$$V(Q,T)=f(Q)T,$$ and
$$V(Q,T)=g(T)Q.$$

How do I prove rigorously that $$V(Q,T)=cTQ,$$ where $c$ is a constant?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V(T,Q) is obviously separable in the following way:

And,
$$
V(Q,T) = f(Q)T = g(T)Q
$$
Then
$$
\frac{V(Q,T)}{T Q}=\frac{f(Q)}{Q} = \frac{g(T)}{T} = c
$$
where $c$ is a constant. Then,
$$
V(Q,T) = c T Q
$$

Comment: How is the "$=c$" justified?

Comment: The "= c" is justified because the functions to the left of the "= c" are independent of each other and vary independently yet equal to each other.  This is only possible if these functions such as $$\frac{f(Q)}{Q}$$ and so on are each equal to a constant.  Note, this is a standard "trick" of the method of solving partial differential equations by the method of separation of variables.

Answer (score 1):

$V(x,x)=f(x)x = g(x)x$ and so $f=g$.

$V(T,Q)=f(T)Q$ and $V(Q,T) = f(T)Q$ so $V(T,Q)=V(Q,T)$

$V(Q,1) = f(Q) = V(1,Q) = f(1)Q$ so $f(Q) = f(1)Q$.

So $V(Q,T)=f(1)QT$.

Comment: This is brilliant - thanks Paul. I accepted K7PEH's answer I because I can only accept one answer, and that proof seemed more straightforward to me. Thanks also for asking the =c question because I had that question too.